# GuzzleHttp Client - post random form data

Tags: php, httpclient, guzzle

Let's start with example.

if I have fixed form parameter (name , email , phone) then Guzzle Post method code would be like this :

```
public function test(Request $request){
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

    $url = www.example.com

    $res = $client->post($url.'/article',[
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'],
        'body' => json_encode([
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'write_article' => $request['article'],
            'phone' => $request['phone'],
        ])
    ]);
}
```

Above code is working perfectly.

But when don't have fix form parameter then How to send data using Guzzle ?

Foe example first time when I have submited form I have **name , email , phone** field. next time may be fields would be **name , email , phone , father_name , mother_name, interest , etc..** . next time may be it would be **name , email , father name**

So How to work with this dynamic form field situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function test(Request $request)
{
    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $url = 'www.example.com';

    $body = [];

    // exceptions, for when you want to rename something
    $exceptions = [
        'article' => 'write_article',
    ];

    foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($exceptions[$key])) {
            $body[$exceptions[$key]] = $value;
        } else {
            $body[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    $res = $client->post($url.'/article',[
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'],
        'body' => json_encode($body)
    ]);
}
```

Comment: On the other end I mean **/article** route end how to get body parameter ? I tried **print_r($request)** on that side but can't get anything. Any idea ?

Comment: How are you trying to see that?

Comment: if I pass **$body[name] = john;** from guzzle to **/article** route then how to get **name=jone** on **/article** side ?

Comment: That depends heavily on your framework, but one way of doing it is by looking in the `$_POST` superglobal.

Comment: I'm using laravel php framework and code is like this : ** public function article(Request $request){ return $request; }  ** but request array don't give me name parameter. can you help me ?

Comment: Try `$request->input('name')`. Be advised that that data will be returned to the Guzzle client and not visible in the browser.